# Run script from context menu on file with spaces in filename on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bash, shell-script, context-menu

I have a right click context menu to rename files. This is created by importing the following to the registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\add_date]
@="Add date to filename"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\add_date\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\mintty.exe --exec \"/usr/bin/bash\" --login -i -c \"/c/Users/V/OneDrive\\ -\\ A/src/insert_date/insert_date.sh '%1'; sleep 2"
```

I also tried the alternive with double quotes:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\add_date]
@="Add date to filename"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\add_date\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\mintty.exe --exec \"/usr/bin/bash\" --login -i -c \"/c/Users/V/OneDrive\\ -\\ A/src/insert_date/insert_date.sh \\\"%1\\\"; sleep 2"
```

However, when a filename contains spaces, the filename is not passed to the script, but something like `000000~2.pptx` (The zeros are the first 6 characters of my filename). For the renaming I need the original filaname. How to solve this?

The renaming itself is done with a bash script.

Comment: use double quotes

Comment: The double quote version shows the same behaviour

Comment: of course, you did not quote the path but the whole commandline

Comment: @alecxs: Then I do not understand your suggestion. Can you post an example (or a modification of my problem statement) as an answer to this question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9560709